# MySQL licensing

Tags: mysql, clustering, mysql-cluster, license

I have looked at a few questions posted in stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225987/can-someone-explain-mysqls-license-and-what-it-means-to-closed-source-developme

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620696/mysql-licensing-and-gpl

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921437/is-it-legal-to-using-mysql-in-commercial-environment

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/alternative-opensource-free-to-mysql-cluster-manager-client

They talk about licensing issues with redistributing MySQL.

My question is a little different. Lets say I have a product which uses databases through jdbc. It can connect to any database MySQL, SQL Server or anything else. And I am not bundling MySQL or any other database with the product.

However, if a customer wants to use MySQL Cluster with my product - can he do so free if he isn't interested in support?

Or if a reseller of my product who gives turnkey solutions to the customer - if they want to install my product & MySQL Cluster at a customer site, can they use MySQL Cluster free of charge without support?

Or is there any other free product which can be used with "MySQL Community Edition" or a similarly free MySQL Edition to provide functionality similar to "MySQL Cluster" if clustering supporting is not necessary.

The customer has a budget enough to pay for MySQL Standard but not for MySQL Cluster & is looking at how to work best within his budget.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.  Questions on licensing should be referred to the vendor, and an answer obtained in writing from them.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend completing the inquiry form here and one of the advisors can come back to you with the best advise:
http://www.mysql.com/about/contact/

Comment: A lot of folks who work for MySQL seem to be around in this forum. I am not sure why nobody replied here - which would help not just me but also the whole stackexchange community?